# WPF UserControl: Invoke usercontrol's public method from viewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have a MVVM WPF application in C#, NET 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008.

From the app main xaml I import a user control.

This user control has some public methods, there are two I am interested in.

One method to start an animation and another to stop it.

From my view's constructor in code-behind (xaml.cs), I call the user control public method to start the animation to show it to user while I am loading some data into my gridview within listview. The method to load the data is called form my view model.

So now, when the loading task is finished, I need to call the another user control public method to stop animation but I do not know how to do this from my view model.

Any ideas? I cannot touch the user control as this is not mine.

Below some piece of code.

**XAML**:

```
xmlns:controlProgress="clr-namespace:Common.XAML.Controls.Progress;assembly=Common.XAML"

<controlProgress:Progress x:Name="Progress"  
                        Grid.ZIndex="3" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                        Width="150"  
                        CustomText="Loading...">
```

**Code-behind (xaml.cs):**

```
    public MyView(ViewModelSession vm)
        : base(vm)
    {            
        InitializeComponent();

        Progress.StartAnimation();
    }
```

**View Model:**

```
    public MyViewModel(Session session)
        : base(session)
    {            
        this.LoadDataIntoGridView(); 
    }
```

Comment: "I cannot touch the user control as this is not mine." Then you are out of luck because the view model has no reference to the view so it cannot call any of its methods directly.

Comment: I have just posted my answer when saw that evil line... I deleted 
 it immediately..

Comment: Wrap the UC you can't touch in a UC you can.  Then bind your VM to the outer UC.  You can react to state changes in the VM from the outer UC's codebehind and do whatever you want to the wrapped UC.  Show it, hide it, call methods on it, punch it in the face, whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) Interface e.g. create an ViewModelBase

```
public class ViewModelBase
    : INotifyPropertyChanged
{      
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;  

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then you use this for your ViewModel and add a Property IsLoading

```
 public class MyViewModel : ViewModelBase
{            
    private bool _isLoading;

    public bool IsLoading
    {
      get { return _isLoading; }
      set
      {
        if(_isLoading == value) return;
         _isLoading = value;
         OnPropertyChanged();
      }
}
```

Then in your View Codebehind use the PropertyChanged event of the ViewModel to Start/Stop Animation.

Then you can set the bool in your ViewModel to start stop closing animation
in your view

UPDATE

```
public class MyView
{
    private readonly MyViewModel _viewModel;

    public MyView(MyViewModel viewModel)
          : base(viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        _viewModel.PropertyChanged +=OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == nameof(MyViewModel.IsLoading))
        {
            if (_viewModel.IsLoading)
            {
                Progress.StartAnimation();
            }
            else
            {
                Progress.StopAnimation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he means he cant touch the controlProgress user control

Comment: That could make sense, in which case it is possible. Nevertheless **new MyViewModel().PropertyChanged +=OnPropertyChanged;** is not correct, but **_viewModel.PropertyChanged +=OnPropertyChanged;**

Comment: @Mainpat Yes, I mean I cannot touch the controlProgress user control and your solution works fine for me. thx. Only one thing, OnPropertyChanged method, in .NET 3.5, nameof is not supported ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could put a boolean property in your view model to track if the loading has been completed, after that the property will be set to true.

```
 public class MyViewModel
    {

        public bool IsLoadComplete { get; set; }
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            this.LoadDataIntoGridView();
        }
    }
```

Then in your codebehind you can start a Task to track changes in that property of the DataContext:

```
 public MyView(MyViewModel vm)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Progress.StartAnimation();

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var dataContext = DataContext as MyViewModel;
                while (true)
                {
                    if (dataContext.IsLoadComplete)
                        break;
                    Task.Delay(100);
                }
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { Progress.StopAnimation(); }));
            });
        }
```

You have to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to queue the call in the UI thread. Of course this is not a ready-to-production solution. You may provide Datacontext until View has been constructed in which case you must refactor, also you may keep track of the task you have just started and may be support cancellation with a CancellationToken. This is only a sample